# org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of with volley and php

Tags: php, android, json, exception, android-volley

yesterday I came across the error mentioned below, so I started looking for similar questions on stackoverflow...but none of them seemed to help:(

My guess is that im getting no response from the server but I cant come up with an idea how to fix that. Im using like the same code in some other activities (of course with other functions) but al of them are working perfectly fine. 
The only thing that changed is that I used Update table for the first time but I cant see how that would result in the following error.

I hope you can help me.

The strange thing is if the

```
$anzahlrows == 1
```

is true and there is no more error in the php file with the query (like usual) than I get in android:

```
Register Response: {"success":true,"error_msg":"Sie wurden erfolgreich angelegt!"}
I/jsonResponse: {"success":true,"error_msg":"Sie wurden erfolgreich angelegt!"}
```

and everything works fine....

**This is the error im getting:**

```
org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of
```

**in the line of**

```
JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
```

**This is the code in android studio:**

```
Response.Listener<String> responseListener = new Response.Listener<String>() {


                    //  this gets called on response
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {


                        Log.d("Response:", "Register Response: " + response);
                        //  check for boolean success from php
                        try {
                            JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
                            Log.i("jsonResponse", jsonResponse.toString());
                            boolean success = jsonResponse.getBoolean("success");


                            //  if true from php start LoginActivity
                            if (success){
                                Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, jsonResponse.getString("error_msg"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                Intent intent = new Intent(RegisterActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
                                RegisterActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
                            }

                            //  if false build an AlertDialog
                            else {
                                Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, jsonResponse.getString("error_msg"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                };

                //  call register request and transfer string username and password
                RegisterRequest registerRequest = new RegisterRequest(email, password, matrikelnummer, firstName, surname, responseListener);
                RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(RegisterActivity.this);
                queue.add(registerRequest);
```

**This is my PHP File:**

```
if (isset($_POST["email"]) or isset($_POST["password"]) or isset($_POST["matrikelnummer"]) or isset($_POST["firstName"]) or isset($_POST["surname"])) {

$email = $_POST["email"];
$password = $_POST["password"];
$matrikelnummer = $_POST["matrikelnummer"];
$firstName = $_POST["firstName"];
$surname = $_POST["surname"];

$query = "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE Matrikelnummer ='$matrikelnummer'";
if ($result=mysqli_query($con,$query)) {

    $anzahlrows = mysqli_num_rows($result);


    if($anzahlrows == 1) {


        $query = "UPDATE Users SET email = '$email' ,password = '$password',firstName = '$firstName', surname = '$surname' WHERE Matrikelnummer = '$matrikelnummer'";
        if ($result=mysqli_query($con,$query)) {

            $response["success"] = TRUE;
            $response["error_msg"] = "Sie wurden erfolgreich angelegt!";
            echo json_encode($response);
            exit;

        } else {
            $response["success"] = FALSE;
            $response["error_msg"] = "Fehler bei der INSERT SQL Abfrage";
            echo json_encode($response);
            exit;
        }



    } 
    else {
        $response["success"] = FALSE;
        $response["error_msg"] = "Die angegebene Matrikelnummer ist nicht verfügbar";
        echo json_encode($response);
        exit;


    }
} 
else {
    $response["success"] = FALSE;
    $response["error_msg"] = "Fehler bei der SQL Abfrage";
    echo json_encode($response);
    exit;
}

}
else {
$response["success"] = FALSE;
$response["error_msg"] = "Required parameters missing!";
echo json_encode($response);
exit;
}
```

**The Log shows following:**

```
D/Response:: Register Response: 
W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of 
W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONTokener.syntaxError(JSONTokener.java:449)
W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:97)
W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:156)
.
.
.
```

Comment: You state :: "and everything works fine.... This is the error im getting:" If everything works fine, then what is the issue? Or if there a response you get that is causing the error, then please show the JSON response that is causing the error!

Comment: @Barns it works fine if  **$anzahlrows == 1** is true... but when the php file schould execute anything where it should send success as false the output is just nothing....or with other words the jsonresponse is like you can see in the log nothing

Comment: What I usually do with my PHP code is create a response before I enter my 'if (isset($_POST["email"]) ` code starts. Then at each `if/else` statement create an appropriate response-- just as you have, with the exception that I do not echo the response and exit. My final statement is where I use the echo response such that it will echo my response regardless of what happens between. I will post an example in a couple of minutes.

Answer (score 0):

I usually create a response in my PHP code before my code enters the `if (isset($_POST["email"])` code starts. Then at each `if/else` statement I create an appropriate response-- just as you have, with the exception that I do not echo the response and exit. My final statement is where I use the echo response such that it will echo my response regardless of what happens between.

```
<?php

// array for JSON response
$response = array();
$response["success"] = 0;
$response["message"] = "Error before Parameters";

// check for post data
if (isset($_POST["id"])) {

    $id = $_POST['id'];

    // include db connect class
    require_once __DIR__ . '/db_config.php';
    // set vars
    $host = DB_SERVER;
    $db   = DB_DATABASE;
    $user = DB_USER;
    $pass = DB_PASSWORD;
    $charset = 'utf8';

    $dsn = "mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db;charset=$charset";
    $opt = [
        PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
        PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
        PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false,
    ];

    // connecting to db
    $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass, $opt);
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM tblConnectionData WHERE ID = :id;';
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $res = $stmt->execute(['id' => $id]);

    /* Check the number of rows that match the SELECT statement */
    if ($res) {
        // success
        $response["success"] = 1;
        $response["data"] = array();

        while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            $data = array();
            $data["id"] = $row["ID"];
            $data["state"] = $row["State"];
            $data["state_abbrev"] = $row["StateAbbrev"];
            $data["city"] = $row["City"];

            array_push($response["data"], $data);
        }
    }
    else {
        /* No rows matched -- do something else */
        // required field is missing
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "No data returned!!";
    }   
}
else {
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Parameters are not correct";
}
// echoing JSON response
echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

This way I always get a response. I also use `int` responses for my "success"  Tag. That way I can differentiate in my client code what went wrong in by checking the `int`value instead of trying to decipher the `string` response.

Notice that I am also using PDO with Prepared Statements. I highly recommend that you also use Prepared Statements to prevent SQL Injection.

Comment: sounds good to me but how can the outcome change of my problem if I only echo one response at the end of the file. I aggree with you that this is probably best practise, but if I organize every situation with an echo json_encode($response) it should send me the response anyway.... but in my app I'm getting no response at all in all cases except if $anzahlrows == 1 :(

Comment: @PatrickNadler :: There could be many reasons for this. Perhaps there is an issue in you `POST` parameters. Change the code as I have suggested and you will be able to see, if you are getting "kicked out" of your PHP code before you get beyond that point.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it with initializing the array at the start of the php file. It normallt works without in my other php files and I dont know why it fixed my problem but it did.

Thanks for the answers anyway!

Do you see any reasons why it worked this way?